# iOS8での位置情報取得のWhenInUse設定でのiBeacon検出は可能か？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ibeacon

iBeacon端末に近づくとLocal Notificationを飛ばすアプリを開発しております。

iOS8から位置情報取得の設定が3種類となり、

- Never
- WhenInUse
- Always

バックグラウンドでのiBeaconの観測については、Alwaysを使用するという認識でしたが
クライアントから「可能であればWhenInUseで」という要望があり調べていたところ、
[こちら](http://im-sei.tumblr.com/post/91824653043/ios-8)のサイトでWhenInUseでもビーコンのレンジングは可能という表記がありました。

didRangeBeaconsがコールされて、
ビーコン端末のメジャー,マイナーさえ取得できれば処理は可能なのですが、
WhenInUseを指定すると、アプリ起動時/バックグラウンド時かまわずdidRangeBeaconが呼ばれません。

WhenInUse許可時のiBeaconのレンジングはどのように取得するかご存知のかたいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhenInUseでの許可時はリンク先のとおり、領域検知ができないので`didEnterRegion`
や`didDetermineState`内でのレンジングが開始できません。なので、アプリが
立ち上がったタイミング等でBluetoothの状態を確認し、`startRangingBeaconsInRegion`
を実行してレンジングを開始するような形になるかと思います。

ただしBeacon信号を受けたタイミングでLocal Notificationを実施するアプリ
には領域検知が必須なように思いますので、Alwaysで許可をもらうようにする
必要があるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり、バックグラウンドで検知する場合はAlwaysでないといけないのですね。まさに求めていた回答でした。ありがとうございます。